# Ruby URL.parse error

Tags: ruby, exception, net-library

Here is my ruby program

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

begin
    url = URI.parse("http://google.com")
rescue Exception => err
    p err
    exit
end

http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port) 
res = http.head("/")
p res.code
```

It works fine, however if I remove http:// from URL.parse(), It gives me this error:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1196:in `addr_port': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) ...
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1094:in `request'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:860:in `head'
```

Is it the correct way to handle Exception ?

I know maybe the URL is not correct, but It should raise an exception URI::InvalidURIError instead of accepting and continue the program ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you say `u = URI.parse('http://google.com')`, you'll get a `URI::HTTP` back and the `u.port` will have a default of 80. If you say `u = URI.parse('google.com')`, you'll get a `URI::Generic` back with the `u.port` will be `nil` as will `u.host`.

So, when you do this:

```
url  = URI.parse('google.com')
http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
```

You're really doing this:

```
http = Net::HTTP.new(nil, nil)
```

and `Net::HTTP` doesn't like that very much at all. You could try something like this instead:

```
if(str.to_s.empty?)
    # complain loudly about a missing str
end
begin
    url = URI.parse(str)
    url = URI.parse('http://' + str) if !url.scheme

    if(url.scheme != 'http' && url.scheme != 'https')
        # more complaining about bad input
    end

    http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
    #...
rescue URI::Error => e
    # even yet more complaining
end
```

That sort of thing should bypass the exception completely and cover a few other things that you might be interested in.

Answer (score 3):

You have to specifically catch `URI::InvalidURIError`, as it is not a descendant of `Exception`. See:

```
irb(main):002:0> URI::InvalidURIError.is_a?(Exception)
=> false
```

So the fix for your code would be:

```
begin
    url = URI.parse("http://google.com")
rescue URI::InvalidURIError => err
    p err
    exit
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but still it doesn't catch the error when URI.parse("google.com")

Comment: Oh, you're right. I didn't read your question clearly enough, my answer doesn't really answer it. Nonetheless, it is a valid fix for that code =).

Comment: @iKid, I added another answer that answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is not to let any exception happen at all, but to check your conditions beforehand. Like this:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

begin
    url = URI.parse("http://google.com")
rescue URI::InvalidURIError => err
    p err
    exit
end

if url.host && url.port
    http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port) 
    res = http.head("/")
    p res.code
else
        p 'Error parsing url'
end
```

Comment: This approach only works if the receiver honors HEAD requests. Not all web servers honor HEAD requests.

Comment: @rantler, while that's true, my approach has nothing to do with the head requests. That part of my answer was copied directly from the OP's code -- I'm assuming the OP knows that the server under question responds to HEAD requests, and if it doesn't, then that's a completely independent issue. It has nothing to do with my answer to the question.